# How do I toggle multiple displays separately in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I have multiple posts which I am getting from an api request. I would like there to be a toggle for each post, so someone can click it and the rest of the information for the post will show up. How I currently have it set up when the click the toggle "Show More" it opens up all the displays for all of the posts. I'm using the NPM react-toggle-display package. How can I set it up so each post can toggle it displays simultaneously from the other posts?

Posts.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from './posts.css';
import ToggleDisplay from 'react-toggle-display';

class Posts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      show : false
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/posts')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({posts: response.data})
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <div class="ui section divider"></div>
        {this.state.posts.map((post) => {
          return(
            <div key={post.id}>
              <img class="image" src={post.image}/>
              <p>
                <button onClick={ () => this.handleClick() }>Show More</button>
                {post.title}
              </p>
              <ToggleDisplay show={this.state.show}>
                <p>
                  {post.body}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.link }} />
                </p>
              </ToggleDisplay>
              <div class="ui section divider"></div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
  );
}

}

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this, but it basically boils down to having a bool for each of the posts.

If you want to keep all the state in the posts container, then you could add a field to each of the posts that keeps track of whether or not the post is open:

```
this.setState({posts: response.data.map(post => ({ ...post, show: false }))})
```

And then render the toggle like this:

```
<ToggleDisplay show={post.show}>{...}</ToggleDisplay>
```

Another way would be to create a new Post component that keeps track of it's own state.

Comment: Thanks, I just created a new Post component and kept track of the states there and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You could make `show` into an object where each key is a `post` id with a boolean value that you can use for showing that particular post instead.

**Example**

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    show: {}
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      show: { ...prevState.show, [id]: !prevState[id] }
    }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/posts")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <div class="ui section divider" />
        {this.state.posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <img class="image" src={post.image} />
              <p>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(post.id)}>
                  Show More
                </button>
                {post.title}
              </p>
              <ToggleDisplay show={this.state.show[post.id]}>
                <p>{post.body}</p>
                <p>
                  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.link }} />
                </p>
              </ToggleDisplay>
              <div class="ui section divider" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```